# Docker: container exits, but it still looks like running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, restart, availability

I have a Docker service (specifically MongoDB). After some kind of failure (specifically No space left on device), it gets weird:

1. Command `docker-compose logs --follow --tail=10 -t service-name` exits and writes `service-name exited with code 14`. When I run `docker-compose up service-name`, it attempts to start the container.
2. However, `docker ps` shows the service running and "Up 2 days".
3. When the underlying issue is resolved (i.e., some space is freed), the service doesn't restart automatically, although docker-compose.yaml contains `restart: unless-stopped`. It however starts after I tell explicitly Docker to do so (i.e., `docker-compose up some-service`).

Why does this happen? Is there some better solution than just running `docker-compose up -d <list of services>` every minute?

Excerpt from docker-compose.yaml:

```
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
    - PUID=1000
    - PGID=1000
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:…:27017
    volumes:
    - …:/data/db
    - "…:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Excerpt from `docker ps`:

```
144a…   mongo:5   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago     Up 5 hours       127.0.0.1:…->27017/tcp    mongodb
```

Failed attempts to start the container:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up mongodb
Starting mongodb ... error

ERROR: for mongodb  Cannot start service mongodb: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/…/merged: no space left on device

ERROR: for mongodb  Cannot start service mongodb: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/…/merged: no space left on device
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Sounds like the primary process in the container itself did not terminate (this is what determines whether the container restarts). Is this a custom image?

Comment: @Turing85 It is a vanilla `mongo:5` container. I see, it partially looks like running (docker ps), but partially like terminated (`mongodb exited with code 14` in docker-compose logs, docker-compose up service-name tries to start it).

Comment: What do  you mean by "tries to start it"? What happens if docker tries to start that container? Could it be that you have - in fact - two containers running (one suck, one trying to start)? Can you post the `docker-compose.yml`, as well as the output of `docker ps` and `docker ps -a`?

Comment: @Turing85 Added excerpts from `docker-compose.yaml` and `docker ps`, as well as what happens when I try to start the service before adding free space. Note that it is not a surprise that it fails, it is a surprise that it attempts to start it, although `docker ps` shows it running.

Comment: Hm... have you tried destroy the whole deployment (via `docker compose down`) and re-deploy (via `docker compose up`)?

Comment: @Turing85 It still behaves the same.